# when reading calendar events how to seperate Date into Date Month Year and save them in three variables

Tags: android, calendar

This is my code and i'm trying to read calendar events and get only the date,month and year of the event into three seperate variables.

```
public void read_calendar(){
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), new String[]{ "calendar_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null, null, null);
    //Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "name" }, null, null, null);
    String add = null;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String[] CalNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int[] CalIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < CalNames.length; i++) {
        CalIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
        CalNames[i] = ""+new Date(cursor.getLong(3))+"\n"+ cursor.getString(1);
        if(add == null)
            add = CalNames[i];
        else{
            add += CalNames[i];
        }
        textView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView3.setText(add);

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: use "dd MM yyyy" , check out my updated ans

Comment: chenged........

Answer (score 0):

This how you can able to Split **date month and year**.

```
      CalNames[i] = "" + new Date(cursor.getLong(3));
                DateFormat sdf;

                try {


                    // Tue Jan 27 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016
                    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
                    Date date = sdf.parse(CalNames[i]);
                    //sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMM yyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
                    CalNames[i] = sdf.format(date);
                    String[] datesArray = CalNames[i].split(" ");
                    String _date = datesArray[0];
                    String _month = datesArray[1];
                    String _year = datesArray[2];
    //                Log.e("DATE S:", ":" + CalNames[i]);
                    Log.d("DATE S:", _date + "\n" + _month + "\n" + _year);

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: in this code _date got "friday", _month got "jan". i need the number. example: _date output should output the day of month.("27"), _month output should output the month number.("1"). _year is get the correct one.("2017"). can you edit the code to output the dates, not the string values

Comment: i checked the updated code and string _date,_month,_year doesn't get values. i checked them by insert there values into a textbox.texbox does not show anything.last time it shows the date and month string values. i think try method is not working.

Comment: it worked. but my necessity is not completed. i need to get all the calendar events and according to the year,month,date, and sort them and update several textviews according to date month and year. can you help in that.

Answer (score 0):

```
// I have Formatted the date object as per requirement.
// eg 26-09-2016
public void read_calendar(){
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), new String[]{ "calendar_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null, null, null);
    //Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "name" }, null, null, null);
    String add = null;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String[] CalNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int[] CalIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < CalNames.length; i++) {
        CalIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
        Date dateObj = new Date(cursor.getLong(3));
        String sdfCalDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(dateObj);

        CalNames[i] = ""+ sdfCalDate+"\n"+ cursor.getString(1);
        if(add == null)
            add = CalNames[i];
        else{
            add += "\n \n"+CalNames[i];
        }
        textView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView3.setText(add);

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: i'm developing calendar and i need to be synced it with deafult android calendar. i need to get default calendar events one by one and according to year,month,date, a textview in my calendar app should update. as a example if there is a event in 2017/01/30 in default calendar, my calendar also should highlight that day.days are in textviews.i need to check event dates using if function and highlight relevant textview.